# different htpasswd files per domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

I've 2 domains e.g. foo.com and bar.com which share the same document root.
The sites are protected by a .htaccess file

```
AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
AuthName "No Access"
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET POST PUT>
    require valid-user
</Limit>
```

how can I set the AuthUserFile depending on the host?

**pseudocode:**

```
if (host == foo.com) {
    AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd_foo
} else {
    AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd_bar
}
AuthName "No Access"
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET POST PUT>
    require valid-user
</Limit>
```

If this is not possible are there any other ways to get different logins for the 2 domains?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting it up like this:

```
#site1.com
setenvIfNoCase Host site1\.com pass_1
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Site1.com Login Required"
AuthUserFile "/home/userdir/.htpasswds/site1.pwd"
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=pass_1
Satisfy any

#site2.com
setenvIfNoCase Host site2\.com pass_2
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Site2.com Login Required"
AuthUserFile "/home/user_dir/.htpasswds/site2.pwd"
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=pass_2
Satisfy any
```

Comment: this doesn't work. it always uses the second part. I assume it completely overrides the first one.